# WPF ResourceDictionary Item has already been added using ComponentResourceKey

Tags: wpf, exception, resourcedictionary, componentresourcekey

I have the following ResourceDictionary that gets merged into my Themes/Generic.xaml file

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:RequirementResourceRelation}" x:Key="{x:Static local:Resources.RequirementResourceRelationListTemplateKey}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock MinWidth="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="3,0" Text="{Binding Resource.Name, TargetNullValue=Loading...}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="-" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="3,0" Text="{Binding Path=RelationType, TargetNullValue=Loading...}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:RequirementResourceRelation}" x:Key="{x:Static local:Resources.RequirementResourceRelationListTemplate2Key}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock MinWidth="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="3,0" Text="{Binding Requirement.Name, TargetNullValue=Loading...}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="-" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="3,0" Text="{Binding Path=RelationType, TargetNullValue=Loading...}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I'm trying to create two different data templates for the same DataType with different ComponentResourceKey. As you can see one of the keys has a 2 appended to it.

In my local:Resources class I have the following which is the ComponentResourceKey I'm using.

```
    public static ComponentResourceKey RequirementResourceRelationListTemplateKey {
        get {
            return new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(Resources), "RequirementResourceRelationListTemplate");
        }
    }

    public static ComponentResourceKey RequirementResourceRelationListTemplate2Key {
        get {
            return new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(Resources), "RequirementResourceRelationListTemplate2");
        }
    }
```

This works if I have only one of the DataTemplates in there, but once I add the second one I get an exception that says:

```
Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'DataTemplateKey(HR.TrackingTool.Model.RequirementResourceRelation)'  Key being added: 'DataTemplateKey(HR.TrackingTool.Model.RequirementResourceRelation)'
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Add(Object key, Object value)
   at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.SetKeys(IList`1 keyCollection, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.SetDeferrableContent(DeferrableContent deferrableContent)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfSharedBamlSchemaContext.<Create_BamlProperty_ResourceDictionary_DeferrableContent>b__168(Object target, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member, Object obj, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
```

It seems that the ResourceDictionary ignores the key when adding a DataTemplate. Does the ResourceDictionary ignore the key property when it's using a ComponentRelationKey ?

Any way around this exception ?

Thanks,
Raul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you reference your DataTemplate by key, can't you just leave out the DataType-specification?
Without
     DataType="{x:Type model:RequirementResourceRelation}"
(which is apparently the key for the added item) your x:Key should be used as the key.

Comment: Awesome work around. I have submitted this as a bug to Microsoft. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/581761/resource-dictionary-ignores-componentresourcekey-when-adding-a-datatemplate?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: This bug is still active. Incredible!! I am adding two styles for a TextBlock to an app resources dictionary. Stuck with this bug. Completely, utterly frustrating. I want to smash my screen with my keyboard. Microsoft blows. Period.

Comment: That being said, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040804/xaml-mergeddictionaries-throwing-xmlparseexception-item-has-already-been-adde) fixed it for me. I am losing too much hair.

Answer (score 13):

Apparently the issue is as stated, sort of.  The order of the declaration of the style matters.

When the first attribute for two styles for the same **TargetType** is the **TargetType** e.g.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="_defaultRuleTextBlockStyle">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="_tinySourceCodeTextBlockStyle">
```

then you get the error. It seems to ignore the Key: attribute and as stated uses the TargetType value as the dictionary key e.g. "{x:Type TextBlock}"

When the first element of two styles for the same **TargetType** is the **x:Key**, then you do not, as shown below.

```
<Style x:Key="_defaultRuleTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
<Style x:Key="_tinySourceCodeTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
```

Doesn't matter if you move the crap around I guess.  WOrd to the wise, always start with the **x:Key**, but this is a really stupid error.

Comment: Best answer in IMO. Had me stuck for a while and doubting my whole understanding of WPF. Didn't realise that the order of the parameters in XAML ever made a difference but apparently it does.

Comment: I would NEVER have been able to figure this out on my own. Well done!

Comment: Nice find. Attribute order shouldn't matter (should it)? Didn't think I was doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `DataTemplate`(s) inside the `<Resources>` element of another control.

In **Silverlight** this worked just fine:

```
<ResourceDictionary     
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 >
    <!--Template 1-->
    <DataTemplate DataType="VMType" x:Key="Template1">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
    <!--Template 2-->
    <DataTemplate DataType="VMType" x:Key="Template2">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
    <!--Control Style, references the two templates above-->
    <Style TargetType="ControlType">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ControlType">
                    <Grid Background="White" Margin="0">          
                        ...
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

BUT in **WPF**, I had to move the 3 templates inside the control:

```
<ResourceDictionary     
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 >
    <Style TargetType="ControlType">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ControlType">
                    <Grid Background="White" Margin="0">          
                        <!--MOVED HERE INSTEAD OF THE ROOT-->              
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <!--Template 1-->
                            <DataTemplate DataType="VMType" x:Key="Template1">
                                ...
                            </DataTemplate>
                            <!--Template 2-->
                            <DataTemplate DataType="VMType" x:Key="Template2">
                                ...
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        ...
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now it works in both WPF and Silverlight without the error.